# CocoPods did not download Google-Mobile-SDK. How can I fix this?

Tags: ios, xcode, admob, cocoapods

I am trying to add Google-Mobile-SDK into my Xcode project by using CocoaPods. I have created podFile to my project. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvRID.png)

Then, in this podFile, I added this line pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcoWN.png)

Then in terminal, I typed cd Desktop/testBanner5. testBanner5 is name of my project.
Then I typed pod install and pressed enter. I was expecting that this will download Google-Mobile-SDK. Instead, it showed me this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tclAz.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPjW1.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrLlC.jpg)

What should I do in order to fix that problem?

Answer (score 0):

> try delete `pod "Google-Mobile-SDK"` and execute `pod install` in terminal. if you have same error, best way reinstall cocoapods

Comment: sorry I am wrong. 

`
target testBanner5 do
 pod "Google-Mobile-SDK"
end

target testBanner5Test do
 #pod "Google-Mobile-SDK"
end

target testBanner5UITest do
 #pod "Google-Mobile-SDK"
end
`

Answer (score 0):

sorry I am wrong.

```
target 'testBanner5' do
 pod "Google-Mobile-SDK"
end

target 'testBanner5Test' do
 #pod "Google-Mobile-SDK"
end

target 'testBanner5UITest' do
 #pod "Google-Mobile-SDK"
end
```